# Placement of pronoun "y" in second-person reflexive imperative "prends-toi-y" or "prends-y-toi"

Tags: ordre-des-mots, impératif, y

Salut à tous !

I want to conjugate "s'y prendre" into the second person imperative form.

According to this [grammar guide](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/double-pronoun-order/), "y" should go after all personal pronouns. Therefore, it should be "prends-toi-y" --> "prends t'y"

However, [reverso](https://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-french-verb-s%27y%20prendre.html) seems to think that "prends-y-toi" is the correct form. Is it a mistake?

Comment: What is your context? For example: **Il faut savoir comment s'y prendre**. A typical usage. Il faut savoir comment t'y prendre. with the second person pronoun.

Comment: @Lambie I don't have a real context; I was teaching myself imperatives and this question just popped up in my head

Comment: What exactly are you trying to say? [Also, please correct: Salut à **tous**.] :) Are you actually trying to say "Take it"?

Comment: @Lambie I was learning French imperatives on Lawless French, and, upon learning the rule of order of pronouns, I was like, "so how do we form imperatives with *y*, as in *s'y prendre*?" So I went ahead and posted this thread. There is no real context in which I'm trying to use the expression

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. So, *here is the problem*: s'y prendre means: to go about something. As in: *Je ne sais pas (comment) m'y prendre*. I don't know how to go about this/that/it. As you can see, s'y prendre would not be used in the imperative. Follow me? :) I can't "order" you to go about something.

Comment: @Lambie I'm contemplating the sense of "go ahead and handle it", "get it done", "get started tackling it", as something your boss would say in face of a problem. Also, thanks for the correction :)

Comment: It does not mean that. Believe me. What you actually wanted to say would have been useful in the question, by the way. Because then someone could tell you how to actually say that. For example: prendre [quelque chose] en charge....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Object pronoun ordering in imperatives has been a longstanding issue and is a lot less fixed than textbook grammars describe.

The prescribed standard is similar to the one described in the question's first link: V - le/la/les - me/te/lui/nous/vous/leur - en/y, with *-me* and *-te* shifting to forms similar to their stressed outcome (*-moi, -toi*) when they occur last.

This would output "prends-t'y", which is indeed prescriptively standard. But there's several problems with that:

- There's a lot of variation in usage even without involving *y* and *en*, some of it dialectal, and you'll encounter forms like "donne-me-le", "donne-moi-le" or "donne-le-me", even in literature (exemples taken from *Le Bon Usage*: "Rends-nous-les" (Hugo), "montrez-moi-la" (Proust), Di(te)s-nous-le (Hériat, Monterlant), Tenez-vous-le pour dit (Nerval, Renard, Gide, Mauriac, Cocteau)).
- In the standard, several pronouns change forms depending on their neighbouring context: *-me* and *-te* alternate with *-moi* and *-toi* depending on whether they're the last element in the clitic chain, *-le* has a stable vowel (/lœ/, /lø/, /lɛ/ depending on the dialectal variant), i.e. "donne-le aussi" is pronounced /dɔnlœosi/, not */dɔnlosi/, which is what you'd expect if it was an unstable /ə/, but before *y* and *en*, this vowel elides as if it was /ə/ (amène-l'y) and finally *y* and *en* are often preceded by /z/ through liaison, which has prompted the generalisation of this liaison consonant to contexts in which there shouldn't be one (va là-bas -> vas-y, which should in all logic be spelled "va-z-y")
- The rule saying that *te* and *me* + *y* or *en* give m'en/t'en/t'y/m'y is a generalisation of a phenomenon that could in the classical period mostly be observed with *en* only and with a limited set of verbs, most famously *s'en aller* (i.e. va-t'en). This generalisation never took: people find forms like achète-m'en or amène-m'y awkward, if not fully ungrammatical.

To fix the second problem, speakers have generalised one form in all contexts: the alternation between *me* and *moi* is abandoned and *moi* used everywhere (see the "donne-moi-le mentioned above) except in some regions where *me* is used instead ("donne-le-me"); *le* never loses its vowel (donne-le-z-y); and the z-liaison forms of *en* and *y* are generalised to every context (donne-leur-en -> donne-leur-z-en).

This is going to be extremely frequent, of course, with the very awkward moi+y/en and toi+y/en combinations, where sequences like "donne-moi-z-en" are regularly used instead of the prescribed but abnormal sounding "donne-m'en".

For "s'y prendre", this means "prends-toi-z-y", which is how I'd probably spontaneously form it.

But those forms are subject to some normative pressure, so some speakers take advantage of the variability in enclitic pronoun ordering (problem 1 above) to shift -moi and -z-y: Prends-y-toi. This allows them to use the regularised forms /mwa/ and /zi/ in places where they're prescriptively licit (after a verb where you'd expect the z-liaison for *-z-y* and in the final slot of the pronoun chain for *-moi*). And indeed, like in reverso link, you'll sometimes encounter speakers confidently stating that such forms are prescriptively licit, which they are not.

Comment: Bref, people will generally avoid the imperative form of "s'y prendre" (except negative : "(ne) t'y prends pas comme ça" is ok) knowing it's quasi-impossible to build a fluid sentence with it, or else say it as a joke.

Comment: I gave the example above:  [Il faut] savoir comment s'y prendre. Which can be: t'y prendre. Tu ne sais pas comment t'y prendre.

Comment: Thanks so much for this detailed answer. C'est tout à fait époustouflant.

Comment: @Lambie They're asking about enclitic pronoun ordering with imperative, proclitic pronouns with an infinitive is fairly irrelevant

Comment: @XouDo It's not that people avoid the imperative, it's that the imperative for s'y prendre is meaningless; in French and in the English translation.