# Est-il correct d'écrire "prends-l'y" ?

Tags: grammaire

Bonjour,

Je suis tombé sur ce passage dans *Féerie pour une autre fois I* :

> (...) moi laisse ! moi laisse ! ma fille ! ma femme ! mon gendre ! moi
> laisse ! moi laisse ! Pimprenelle, ma petite amie, **prends-l'y** !
> **prends-l'y** ! moi laisse ! moi laisse ! mon chien ! mon petit André
> aussi ! **prends-l'y** ! **prends-l'y** !

Pensez-vous qu'il est correct d'écrire *prends-l'y* ?

Comment: Question proche: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/47011/placement-of-pronoun-y-in-second-person-reflexive-imperative-prends-toi-y-or/47014

Comment: @jlliagre Merci. Je ne comprends pas très bien cette réponse en anglais. Peut-on penser que "prends-l'y" est plutôt une forme de la langue parlée ?

Comment: Ni parlée ni écrite, c'est une fantaisie de l'auteur. Il y en a d'autres comme *moi laisse* pour *laisse-moi* et le jeu de mot avec chien.

Comment: @jlliagre D'accord, merci beaucoup !

Comment: On peut quand même signaler ceci: Prends-la à un/cet endroit. Un endroit=y.  Cela donnerait: Prends-l'y becoz on peut peut pas laisser: "la-y" Au moins, c'est logique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Céline s'amuse avec cette tournure et aucune règle grammaticale ne l'interdit. Il faut quand même avoir en tête que personne ne dit ***prends-l'y*** « dans la vraie vie » car ce serait incompris.

Pour résoudre ce type de problème, le langage parlé a tendance à substituer des formes spécifiques relâchées où les pronoms restent identifiables comme ***prends-y-la*** voire ***prends-la-z-y***.

La forme ***l'y*** est surtout attestée dans des ouvrages de grammaire :

Le bon usage §44 (sur l'élision des pronoms *le* et *la*) :

> *La* pronom personnel qui suit un impératif sauf s'il précède *en* et *y* :
> *Prends-**la** avec toi.* — Mais : *Cette pomme, mets-**l**'y, tire-**l**'en.*

Grevisse ajoute quand même *Mais ces formes sont peu utilisées*. C'est un euphémisme tant elles sont rarissimes.

On trouve aussi l'exemple ***amène-l'y*** dans la [réponse d'Eau qui dort à une question similaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/47011/placement-of-pronoun-y-in-second-person-reflexive-imperative-prends-toi-y-or/47014).

Comment: Mille mercis !!

Answer (score 1):

*Féerie pour une autre fois* est un roman de Louis-Ferdinand Céline, auteur célèbre pour, entre autres, son style et sa syntaxe très particuliers, inspirés par le langage populaire de la banlieue parisienne au début du 20e siècle.

Bref, ce n'est ni correct ni incorrect : c'est du Céline et c'est inimitable.